# Jquery total price with input box and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, calculator

I have the following simple Jquery code that takes your input number * price to provide total.

I also need to have it include options with radio buttons, if checked +add to total.

Can anyone help me so that I can be able to add radio button options to make this take the input + radio buttons to get total price?

** It would also be nice if the price was Live as you typed/radio checked rather than clicking submit, but does not have to.

I have this so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/4bitlabs/tpkpd/15/

HTML:

```
<p class="list">How many "Linear Feet" of boards do you have?</p>
<input id="amount" />
<div class="addon">Add Paint $10.00<input id="amount" type="radio"value="10.00" class="radio"/></div>
<div class="price">$<label for="amount">0.00</label></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function () {
$('#amount').change(function () {
     var $this = $(this);

    $('label').text((parseFloat($this.val()) * 20.00).toFixed(2))            
});        
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An `Id`s must be unique! Use `class` instead of `Id` or just `$('input[type="text"]')`

Comment: tried that, it lets the radio work, but not the input. it only calculates on input at a time instead of combining them. thanks.

Comment: It because you don't have any event for `radiobutton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your HTML.  IDs should be unique.

I've done a fairly major rewrite, which I think will do what you are looking for.  There are other ways to do it as well, but it should get you started

```
<input id="amount1" class="amount" />
```

I've made the IDs unique,  and given the input boxes a class.

```
<input id="amount2" type="radio" value="10.00" class="radio addOn" data-for="amount1" />
```

The radio buttons also have a class of "addOn" and are attached to an label via the "data-for" tag.

```
$(function () {
    $('.amount').change(function () {
        changeAmount($(this));
    });

    $('.addOn').change(function () {
        var $original = $('#' + $(this).data('for'));
        changeAmount($original);
    });
});
```

There are two ways to change the amount, one via changing the input box with a class of `amount`, one via changing the radio button with a class of `addOn`.  The only difference is that the radio button function figures out what input box it is associated with.

```
function changeAmount($element) {
    var amount = 0;
    amount = parseFloat($element.val()) * 20;
    // this handles the case when the val is not filled in.
    if (isNaN(amount)) {
        amount = 0;
    }
    var id = $element.attr('id');
    $('.radio:checked[data-for="' + id + '"]').each(function () {
        amount += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('label[for=' + id + ']').text(amount.toFixed(2))
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLjQV/3/)

Comment: Thanks. That is what I needed. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bitlabs/62vWH/

Comment: Any Way to make it so that as you type in the input box, it shows in the total without having to click?

Comment: You would use the keypress event instead of the change event for the .amount function

Comment: Thanks Brian, I did not think of that. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use checked property.
And you better do not use duplicated IDs.

```
$(function () {
  $('#amount').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var addPoint = $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked') ? 10 : 0;

    $('label').text((parseFloat($this.val()) * 20.00 + addPoint).toFixed(2))            
  });        
});
```